# Find the minimum number on a tuples list

Tags: list, prolog

I have a list that is composed by tuples, being the first element of the tuple a list and the second element a number:

```
([List],Number)|T]
```

How can i find the minimum value from this list? Does it work the same as finding the number in a list of numbers ?

Thanks!

edit: i have tried this but at some point the backtracking messes up the final result, so im definitely doing something wrong...

```
menor([(L1,Dist)|T],(LR,DistMenor)):-
    menor(T, Dist, (LR,DistMenor)).

menor([], Dist, (LR,Dist)).
menor([(X,Y)|T], Dist, (X,Y)) :-
    Y < Dist,!,
    menor(T, Y, (Path,Cost)).

menor([_|T], Dist, (X,Y)):-
    menor(T, Dist, (Path,Cost)).
```

Comment: Yes, it is basically the same concept. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, i have tried this, but at some point the backtracking messed up the final result, so i think i must be doing something wrong...(i edited the post)

Comment: Prolog doesn't really have tuples. It shouldn't be harmful to construct expressions like that, but usually you see people using minuses instead, as in `X-Y`. I don't know if there is a deeper reason having to do with commas or if it's just style though.

Comment: You didn't implement a correct pattern for min value. You shouldn't use cut. Use a variable instead of `_` in your last clause and include a condition for it. Your base case is wrong. The first argument should not be `[]`. An empty list has no minimum value.